Django.db.utils.OperationalError. Почему отказано в соединении?
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с ошибкой:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost"
(::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on
that host and accepting TCP/IP connections

Локально постгрес включен.
В настройках так:
load_dotenv()
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(
        default=os.getenv('DATABASE_URL'),
        conn_max_age=600,
        conn_health_checks=True, 
        engine='django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
)

в .env все как обычно
DATABASE_URL='postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/db'

Куда копать?

Ну для начала логичный вопрос — а прослушивание порта 5432 в этом локальном постгресе включено?

@andreymal подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу это проверить?
Но если я введу локально команду psql -d db -U user -h localhost -p 5432
то все ок, работает

Если «все ок», то попробуйте заменить localhost на 127.0.0.1, а то вот этот ::1 в тексте ошибки немного смущает

@andreymal спасибо. Но не вышло(
